# Is there a lemma like "∃x. a^x = b" proved in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle, exponent

Does anyone know where a lemma similar to

`∃(x::real). a^x = (b::real)`

might be found? I couldn't find something like that in the 'query', but it seems pretty handy.

Comment: What is `a` or `b` for that matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few more assumptions on `a` and `b` and you need to use the `powr` operator instead of `^`, since `^` is only for the `n`-th power where `n` is a natural number. `powr` on the other hand is for any non-negative real number raised to the power of any other real number. (or similarly for complex numbers)

```
lemma 
  fixes a b :: real
  assumes "a > 0" "a ≠ 1" "b > 0"
  shows   "∃x. a powr x = b"
proof
  from assms show "a powr (log a b) = b" by simp
qed
```